# Compiler support for XSS protection

Tags: compiler-construction, xss, language-design

You can use [tainted strings](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/taint) together with prepared statements to get a bullet-proof protection against SQL injection. Is there a similar language feature to protect users against XSS?

Comment: Wouldn't tainted strings work for XSS too?

Comment: @svick As with all XSS issues, it depends on the context. If the developer decides to allow untrusted user input directly into a `<script>` tag for example (and not wrapped in quotes), then no amount of escaping can realistically prevent XSS. Preventing XSS is about context-sensitive character escaping - any time you ignore the context, you are risking a XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @Gray Would you like to write down an example?

Comment: @svick Probably to a large extent, yes. You might need to include the escape level in the type system. Not impossible in any way.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt `<script> {{input}} </script>` is a simple example that pretty much no amount of escaping would fix since the program was designed to allow user-defined javascript to run on the page. You can easily build a payload url without quotes using String.fromCharCode(), and extract cookies/whatever evil tasks you normally do with XSS. No HTML characters like `<,>,/,",',\,&` needed